# How to get only key and value from stringifying json after API fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, ejs

I'm trying to display only the key and value on an EJS page.

```
<span><%= JSON.stringify(results.conversion_rates) %></span>
```

leaves me with

```
{"USD":1,"AED":3.6721,"ARS":81.0455,"AUD":1.3564,"BGN":1.6324}
```

How could I remove the brackets and quotations?

Here is my server.js route if that helps:

```
app.get('/results', (req, res) => {
  const query = req.query.q;
  axios
    .get(`https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/a66b8aae93f6e7abafe3aab5/latest/${query}`)
    .then(function (response) {
      const currencyPair = `Conversion Rates for ${query}`;
      console.log(response)
      res.render('results', {
        currencyPair,
        results: response.data,
      });
    })
});
```

Comment: I had a similar issue. Please, check if it helps you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63488725/json-bad-format-in-post-method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you need just to remove all quotes and single quotes? For this reason, You don't need to iterate through Object.

```js
let incomeJson = { "USD":1,"AED":3.6721,"ARS":81.0455,"AUD":1.3564,"BGN":1.6324 };

console.log( JSON.stringify(incomeJson).replace(/["']/g, ""));
```

Comment: Thank you. Why the double quote and single quote inside the array? It's giving me a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that ?

```js
let val_JSON = { "USD":1,"AED":3.6721,"ARS":81.0455,"AUD":1.3564,"BGN":1.6324 }

const JSON2Str = jso => Object.entries(jso).reduce((s,[k,v],i)=>s + (i?',':'') + ` ${k}:${v}`,'')



console.log( JSON2Str( val_JSON ) )
```

usage:

```js
<span><%= JSON2Str(results.conversion_rates) %></span>
```